# Salvar segunda linha de um comando no Prompt

Tags: windows

Preciso salvar a segunda linha de um comando no CMD do Windows, ao utilizar o WMIC, ele retorna a chave do produto na segunda linha, mostrando uma mensagem qualquer na primeira. 
Preciso armazenar essa linha em uma variável, para aplicar no comando SLMGR.

```
Comando:<br>

wmic path softwareLicensingService get OA3xOriginalProductKey 

Mensagem de retorno:<br>
```

> OA3xOriginalProductKey 
>  XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX (Preciso
>   dessa linha)

Alguém sabe como fazer isso??

---

Ele pega apenas a primeira linha fazendo isso.
Preciso apenas da segunda linha contendo a chave, pois o slmgr reconhece apenas ela, qualquer outro caractere vai apresentar erro.

Answer (score 1):

Execute o comando no prompt do MS-Dos normalmente adicionando `> arquivo` no final do comando para que o sistema salve a saida nesse arquivo, desse modo:

```
wmic path softwareLicensingService get OA3xOriginalProductKey > saida.txt
```

Depois leia o arquivo texto e processe as linhas que for de seu interesse.

Comment: Mas nesse caso, como faço para ler apenas essa segunda linha, dentro de uma bat?